# client certificate needed when configuring kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, ca, kubectl

:)

I have kubenretes 1.9.3 installed on my local Gentoo Linux cluster.

I'm trying to configure kubectl as documented at https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/scratch/

the kubernetes docs state to configure kubectl with `$CLI_CERT` and `$CLI_KEY`. so far in the documentation I set `$CA_CERT` and `$MASTER_KEY`. don't know which other certificate i need to create that are required.

the docs stated to use `$CLI_CERT` and `$CLI_KEY` but I can't find how to create them.

I used `easyrsa` to create the certificates.

these are the files that I have:

```
./reqs/server.req
./issued/server.crt
./certs_by_serial/577957B555C21B8DC4B1641E97378EFF.pem
./index.txt.attr
./serial
./private
./private/ca.key
./private/server.key
./.rnd
./ca.crt
```

this is the environment variables that I set:

```
export MASTER_IP="192.168.1.3"
export MASTER_CLUSTER_IP="10.0.0.1"

export KUB_DIR="/opt/kubernetes"
export KEYS_DIR="${KUB_DIR}/keys"

export CA_CERT="${KEYS_DIR}/ca.crt"
export MASTER_CERT="${KEYS_DIR}/server.crt"
export MASTER_KEY="${KEYS_DIR}/server.key"

export USER=ufk
export USER_UID=1


export API_SERVER_DIR=${KUB_DIR}/kube-apiserver
export KNOWN_TOKENS_CSV=${API_SERVER_DIR}/known_tokens.csv

export CURRENT_USER=$(who am i | awk '{print $1}')

export CLUSTER_NAME="tux-in-cluster"
export CONTEXT_NAME="tux-in-context"
export CLI_CERT=
export CLI_KEY=

export RSA_BIN=/usr/share/easy-rsa/easyrsa
```

and this is how I created the certificates:

```
echo init pki...
$RSA_BIN init-pki

echo generate CA...
$RSA_BIN --batch "--req-cn=${MASTER_IP}@`date +%s`" build-ca nopass

echo Generate server certificate and key...
$RSA_BIN --subject-alt-name="IP:${MASTER_IP},"\
"IP:${MASTER_CLUSTER_IP},"\
"DNS:kubernetes,"\
"DNS:kubernetes.default,"\
"DNS:kubernetes.default.svc,"\
"DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster,"\
"DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local" \
--days=10000 \
build-server-full server nopass
```

what am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the docs stated to use $CLI_CERT and $CLI_KEY but I can't find how to create them.

You will have a "user" who runs the kubectl command to create e.g. a pod. This "user" needs to prove that it is a legitimate user who has the access to the API server and have the proper authorization to create a pod.

You need to create this user (especially for an administrator) and client certificate/key to prove itself as a legitimate user whose certificate is signed by the ca.crt.

1. Create an admin cert as in The Admin Client Certificate in the [Provisioning a CA and Generating TLS Certificates](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/04-certificate-authority.md) page, for example.
2. Use the admin cert as in [Configuring kubectl for Remote Access](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/10-configuring-kubectl.md) to configure the kubeconfig for the admin user.

To configure additional users, such as operators who start/stop/monitor the cluster, etc, please have a look at [Configure RBAC In Your Kubernetes Cluster](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/) to setup appropriate roles, users, and role bindings to the users.